# Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch occured

Tags: ios, objective-c

Getting the above error when my app launches. The following code is from my AppDelegate .h File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

The following is from my AppDelegate implementation file .m applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//Configure and show the window
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: you need to assign a root view controller to your navigation controller,are u using storyboard or xib ?

Answer (score 16):

add this in your app delegate:

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

Comment: Yes the above line of code solved it. I placed the line at the very bottom of my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method AppDelegate implementation file help much appreciated.

Comment: This answer is missing an important detail - also remove the call to `[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];`.

Answer (score 3):

If you started with an empty template and added a storyboard, you need to do a couple of things:

- In project settings ->General, select your storyboard as the main interface
- You also need to delete the following lines from **Your**AppDelegate.m

  `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];` 
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  `self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`
  `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways, I overcame this was by the following steps:

1) Start Xcode and choose Empty Application

2) Now Goto the File --> New Application under UI

3) Give it a name --> myView

4) Now create a custom Class --> myView

5) Goto the .xib file now and click on the File Owner and under the Class Attribute enter --> myView as the custom Class

6) Now add a button and create an action

7) It should work

Answer (score 0):

Select your target project.Then set your mainstoryboard name from the dropdownlist in summary section.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it does sound stupid, but I got this error because I linked the root view controller with one button's event. This issue was gone when I removed this connection.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2 solution that worked for me  :

Insert the code below in AppDelegate   ->   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```js
self.window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourRootViewController") as? YourRootViewControllerClass
```